# How to set Decimal Value if the field is empty while import data using excel in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I import data from excel sheet using MVC 4. I got data perfectly. But I need to set value 0.0 to one of the decimal field, if data is empty. Can any one help?

My code to get data for particular decimal field below.

```
_vm.Factorial = data[i, 1].ToString() != null ? decimal.Parse(data[i, 1]) : 0;
```

Above one catch the factorial data correctly. I want to set 0.0 or 0 if input value is null or empty .

Comment: Your code should work. What's the issue?

Comment: Its working. But When we got null or empty value for the field, I need to set 0.0 or 0 automatically. but my code throws exception. As it is decimal, I dont know how to set the value..

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I just added 'm' suffix at the end of the 0.0 literal:

```
_vm.Factorial = data[i, 1].ToString() != null ? decimal.Parse(data[i, 1]) : 0.0m;
```

This code as the OP suggest, will handle both null and empty string:

```
_vm.Factorial = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data[i, 1]) ? decimal.Parse(data[i, 1]) : 0.0m;
```

Comment: I tried your one. Sorry still not working.. shows same exception.  
"Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: As I get all the details by string, it shows error.After I did some update on your syntax,its working

Comment: _vm.Factorial = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data[i, 1]) ? decimal.Parse(data[i, 1]) : 0.0m;

Comment: The code should work fine if its null, but it will not handle empty string. Good thing to know you figure it out. I edited the code as per your updated answer as reference to others. @Ben77

Answer (score 0):

Your data may not be text which is convertible to a decimal. Therefore, you have to use the `TryParse` method to try and see if it succeeds.

```
var possibleNum = data[i, 1].ToString();
var num = 0.0m;
if (decimal.TryParse(possibleNum, out num)
{
    _vm.Factorial = num; // succeeded. It is a number
}
else 
{
    // possibleNum is not a number. What do you want to do?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TryParse can be used: try using below

```
decimal value =default(decimal);
 _vm.Factorial = data[i, 1].ToString() != null ? (decimal.TryParse(data[i, 1],out value)==true? value :0.0m ): 0.0m;
```